# Excel print to pdf adding white spaces/margins on right?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub generatepdf()

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesTall = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0)
.RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0)

End With

Range("b3:j43").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("c11").value & "-" & Range("c16").value, openafterpublish:=True

End Sub
```

Whenever I run the code and make pdf, there are white margins on right. Event normal print or save as pdf generating these white spaces.

Tried seetings in page layout and all, still cannot resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to equally balance the white margins on either side of the data using .CenterHorizontally, such as:

```
Sub generatepdf()

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = True
    End With

    Range("b3:j43").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("c11").Value & "-" & Range("c16").Value, openafterpublish:=True

End Sub
```

Another option is, if the data doesn't change width, to use .Zoom and tune the width manually. How I can't see VBA providing access to any finer control than this. Cheers.

Comment: Problem is I have an image at the top and it has to scale/bleed full width at the top. But there is a white space at right which is frustrating..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and fixed it by going to:

File > Options > Advanced > General (section) > and unticking Scale content for A4.